# How to call a method of a class from the same class

Tags: typescript1.4

I got a class with 2 functions.  One of them needs to call the other one both in the same class.  How do you do that ?

```
class a
{
    func1(): string {
        return "test";
    }
    func2() {
        var aTest = this.func1(); // Get an undefined error ??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is completely valid (although func2 does nothing with aTest)

I took what you have and tweaked a little to enable seeing output and renaming class a to class A. Take my code below and play with it here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

```
class A
{
    func1(): string {
        return "test";
    }
    func2() {
        var aTest = this.func1();
        alert(aTest);
    }
}
var a = new A();
a.func2();
```